# Responsive grid using image sprite as CSS background image

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

Wow, this was harder than I anticipated!

We're trying to use an image sprite as CSS background image on a responsive website in a grid.

Please [check out our jsfiddle of the scenario](http://jsfiddle.net/zigojacko/nsvka987/).

So essentially, when this is resized, the background images from the sprite need to be resized to fit the parent container (`<span>`).

I have converted the background image to a `data:image` thinking this would be the first step (although I'm not sure) and now not really sure how I can make the background images from the sprite respond.

Everything I have tried so far ends up displaying the full sprite image in each container in the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using absolute pixel values and background sizes in fluid setting.
Try converting your background-positions to a fluid unit (like percentage) and adding background-sizes to allow the spritesheet to resize with the container.

By removing the inner height of the image container and applying a padding, you can make the container's height ratio stay the same:

```
.credits-grid li span.image {
  background: url(../images/credits.png) no-repeat;
  padding-top: 90%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: 500% auto;
}
```

Then by calculating the percentage coordinates of the sprite's location instead of the pixel value, you can allow it to freely move into place as the container changes size:

```
.credits-grid li span.image.c10 {
  background-position: -26% 50%;
}
```

You can see this in action on this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nsvka987/2/

Comment: Doh. Of course. Thanks man - this gives us enough to go on to get these working nicely. +1 :)